# Is it possible to export a pcap / pcapng from fiddler?

Tags: windows-7, https, fiddler

And, if so, how?

(For my purposes, I don't actually need any protocol information below the application layer, but the tools which work with pcaps provide some useful functionality.)

Comment: Fiddler doesn't have any of the lower stack levels, so it couldn't produce a usable pcap file.  What functionality are you looking for?

Comment: I like filtering using the command line; filtering a specific request into a file and messing around with it in vim. I also just like being able to use Wireshark for a number of reasons (portability, familiarity with the UI, etc.).

Comment: Never used it, but this looks promising: https://github.com/EmergingThreats/fiddler2pcap